# My Sql(MySQL said: #1052 - Column 'hswhouse.whname' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, sql-view

```
create view House as 
SELECT hswhouse.whname,hsitems.description,hsitems.numInStock
from hswhouse
inner join hsitems
inner join hswhouse on hswhouse.whnum = hsitems.whouseNum
where hswhouse.whname = "San Diego"
```

and MySQL said:

> #1052 - Column 'hswhouse.whname' in field list is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

You have table `hswhouse` twice in the query, without aliases, so it is indeed ambiguous to which of them table name `hswhouse` refers.

Looking at your query, one of the `join`s is missing a `on` clause (which is a syntax error in most databases apart from MySQL), and it really seems like you need table `hswhouse` just once. Most likely, you want:

```
create view House as 
SELECT h.whname, i.description, i.numInStock
from hswhouse h
inner join hsitems i on h.whnum = i.whouseNum
where h.whname = 'San Diego'
```